# Machine learning not detecting objects if it's 3 to 4 meters away from the camera

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

been using Google TensorFlow (python), a pre-trained model “efficientdet_d0”, a dataset from Kaggle and Cuda core with 2 GB of VRAM. And successfully trained a custom model in mask and no mask, but my issue is when the object (me or someone else) is 3 to 4 meters far from the camera the object is not detected.

I found something about small objects but I am not sure if it’s the same thing as far objects.

I am fairly new in this field (one month).

my pipeline.config

```
    model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 3
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 512
        max_dimension: 512
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_efficientnet-b0_bifpn_keras"
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.029999999329447746
          }
        }
        activation: SWISH
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.9900000095367432
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
        force_use_bias: true
      }
      bifpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        num_iterations: 3
        num_filters: 64
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 1.0
        x_scale: 1.0
        height_scale: 1.0
        width_scale: 1.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: SWISH
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.9900000095367432
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
          force_use_bias: true
        }
        depth: 64
        num_layers_before_predictor: 3
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
        use_depthwise: true
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 3
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.5
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 1.5
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    add_background_class: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 1
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
      output_size: 512
      scale_min: 0.10000000149011612
      scale_max: 2.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 8e-3
          total_steps: 300000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.0001
          warmup_steps: 2500
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "pre-trained-models/efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 300000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  use_bfloat16: true
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/test.record"
  }
}
```

Code:

```
import os
import tarfile
import threading
import urllib.request
import six
import mysql.connector
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from playsound import playsound
from PIL import Image

DATA_DIR = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')
MODELS_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'models')
for dir in [DATA_DIR, MODELS_DIR]:
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.mkdir(dir)

def soundPlay():
    playsound('Sound.wav')


def get_Center(x, y, w, h): 
    x1 = int(w / 2)
    y1 = int(h / 2)
    cx = x + x1
    cy = y + y1
    return cx, cy

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="tensorflow"
)
# Check if connection was successful
if (mydb):
# Carry out normal procedure
    print("Connection successful")
else:
# Terminate
    print("Connection unsuccessful")

# Download and extract model
MODEL_DATE = '20200711'
MODEL_NAME = 'efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32'
MODEL_TAR_FILENAME = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
MODELS_DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/'
MODEL_DOWNLOAD_LINK = MODELS_DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_DATE + '/' + MODEL_TAR_FILENAME
PATH_TO_MODEL_TAR = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, MODEL_TAR_FILENAME)
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, os.path.join(MODEL_NAME, 'checkpoint/'))
PATH_TO_CFG = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, os.path.join(MODEL_NAME, 'pipeline.config'))
min_score_thresh = 0.50


# Download labels file
LABEL_FILENAME = 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
LABELS_DOWNLOAD_BASE = \
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/master/research/object_detection/data/'
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, os.path.join(MODEL_NAME, LABEL_FILENAME))

# %%
# Load the model
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Next we load the downloaded model

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from centroidtracker import CentroidTracker

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')           # Suppress TensorFlow logging (2)
tracker = CentroidTracker(maxDisappeared=50, maxDistance=50)
# Return a list of physical devices visible to the host runtime.
# Enable GPU dynamic memory allocation
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)

    
# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_CFG)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, is_training=False)

# load the trained model to the empty model
# Restore checkpoint
# expect_partial(): Silence warnings about incomplete checkpoint restores. 
# Warnings are otherwise printed for unused parts of the checkpoint file or object when the Checkpoint object is deleted (often at program shutdown). 
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'ckpt-0')).expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    """Detect objects in image."""
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections, prediction_dict, tf.reshape(shapes, [-1])

# %%
# Load label map data (for plotting)
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Label maps correspond index numbers to category names, so that when our convolution network
# predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility
# functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels
# would be fine.
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS,
                                                                    use_display_name=True)


def run_inference_for_single_image(output_dict):
  # print(output_dict)
  # All outputs are batches tensors.
  # Convert to numpy arrays, and take index [0] to remove the batch dimension.
  # We're only interested in the first num_detections.
  num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections'))
  output_dict = {key:value[0, :num_detections].numpy() 
                 for key,value in output_dict.items()}
  output_dict['num_detections'] = num_detections

  # detection_classes should be ints.
  output_dict['detection_classes'] = (output_dict['detection_classes'] + 1).astype(np.int64)
#   print(output_dict['detection_classes'])
  # Handle models with masks:
  if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
    # Reframe the the bbox mask to the image size.
    detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
              output_dict['detection_masks'], output_dict['detection_boxes'],
               image.shape[0], image.shape[1])      
    detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(detection_masks_reframed > min_score_thresh,
                                       tf.uint8)
    output_dict['detection_masks_reframed'] = detection_masks_reframed.numpy()
    
  return output_dict

def insertToDB(detection_id, class_id, class_name, class_score, class_detection_date):
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    sql = "INSERT INTO cameralogs (detection_id, class_id, class_name, class_score, class_detection_date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    val = (detection_id, class_id, class_name, class_score, class_detection_date)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

    mydb.commit()

    print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")

# %%
# Define the video stream
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# We will use `OpenCV <https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/>`_ to capture the video stream
# generated by our webcam. For more information you can refer to the `OpenCV-Python Tutorials <https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera>`_
import cv2

# cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Free Stock Footage -People wearing face mask- Empty Street- Covid19-.mp4')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://@192.168.1.157:8080/video?resolution=32')



# import numpy as np

centroidId = -1
while True:
    # Read frame from camera
    ret, image_np = cap.read()
    
    image_np = cv2.cvtColor(image_np,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
#     width = 416
#     height = 416
#     dim = (width, height)
#     image_np = cv2.resize(image_np, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
    #percent by which the image is resized
    scale_percent = 100

    #calculate the 50 percent of original dimensions
    width = int(image_np.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(image_np.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    
    dim = (width, height)
    image_np = cv2.resize(image_np, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
#     print(image_np_expanded)



    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
#     print(input_tensor)
    detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    
    detections = run_inference_for_single_image(detections)

    label_id_offset = 1
#     image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

#     cv2.line(image_np_with_detections, (50 , ROI), (1200 , ROI), (255, 0, 0), 3)  # Line


#     print(detected_objects)

#     if len(detected_objects) > 0:

#         for obj in detected_objects[0]:

#             if detected_objects[0]['name'] == "person":
    
#     boxes = np.squeeze(detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy())
#     scores = np.squeeze(detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy())
    boxes = np.squeeze(detections['detection_boxes'])
    scores = np.squeeze(detections['detection_scores'])
    bboxes = boxes[scores > min_score_thresh]

    image_np_with_detections = viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          detections['detection_boxes'],
          detections['detection_classes'],
          detections['detection_scores'],
          category_index,
          instance_masks=detections.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          min_score_thresh=min_score_thresh,
          line_thickness=8)
    image_np_with_detections = cv2.cvtColor(image_np_with_detections,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
#     viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
#         image_np_with_detections,
#         detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
#         (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
#         detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
#         category_index,
#         use_normalized_coordinates=True,
#         max_boxes_to_draw=200,
#         min_score_thresh=min_score_thresh,
#         agnostic_mode=False)

#     print(boxes)
#     print([category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate((boxes + label_id_offset).astype(int)) if detections['detection_scores'][0, index].numpy() > 0.50])
    
    im_width, im_height = image_np.shape[1::-1]
    
    objects = tracker.update(bboxes)
    for (objectId, box)in objects.items():
        ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box

        ymin = ymin * im_height
        xmin = xmin * im_width
        ymax = ymax * im_height
        xmax = xmax * im_width

        x = xmin
        y = ymin
        w = xmax - xmin
        h = ymax - ymin

        mid_point = get_Center(int(x), int(y), int(w),int(h))
        cv2.circle(image_np_with_detections, (mid_point[0], mid_point[1]), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
#         cv2.rectangle(image_np_with_detections, (int(x),int(y)), (int(x) + int(w), int(y) + int(h)), (0,255,0), 2)
        text = "ID: {}".format(objectId)
        cv2.putText(image_np_with_detections, text, (mid_point[0], mid_point[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
#         print(objectId)
        
#         print('first',centroidId)
        if objectId > centroidId:
           detected_objects = [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(detections['detection_classes']) if detections['detection_scores'][index] > 0.50]
#            detected_objects = 'hello'
           
           centroidId = objectId
           today = date.today()
           d4 = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
           if(detected_objects[0]['id'] == 2):
             print('Data',detected_objects[0]['name'])
             thread1 = threading.Thread(target = soundPlay)
             thread1.start()
#              soundPlay
             status = "Not_Wearing_mask_"+str(objectId)+"_"+d4+".jpg"
             cv2.imwrite("Detection_image/"+status, image_np_with_detections)
        
           
#            print(d4)
           insertToDB(int(centroidId), int(detected_objects[0]['id']), str(detected_objects[0]['name']), float(detections['detection_scores'][0]), d4)
#         if(detected_objects[0]['id'] == 2):
#              thread1 = threading.Thread(target = soundPlay)
#              thread1.start()
            
#         if mid_point[1] < (ROI + offset) and mid_point[1] > (ROI - offset):
#             thread1 = threading.Thread(target = soundPlay)
#             thread1.start()

#             cv2.line(image_np_with_detections, (50 , ROI), (1200 , ROI), (0, 0, 255), 3)
#             cv2.imwrite("Cache_Image.jpg", image_np_with_detections)

    # Display output
    cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: "I found something about small objects but I am not sure if it’s the same thing as far objects." -- You're working with 2D images here.  There is no such thing as "near" and "far".  An object farther from the camera becomes smaller.  TF looks for overall similarity.  A small object is not going to be similar to a large object.

Comment: so from what I understand I should prepare my dataset for small object detection?

Comment: Take a look at SSD anchor boxes sizes